# How to set custom traceId in Spring sleuth with opentelemetry

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-sleuth, open-telemetry

I have a usecase where we are sending a message from process A to process B via gcp pub/sub. Tracing is initiated in process A and want to use same traceId in process B. How can i override trace Id in process B when new span is started.

Before using openTelemetry, with Brave i could override traceId using following code

```
private Span createNewSpan(long traceId) {
    TraceContext traceContext = TraceContext.newBuilder()
            .traceId(traceId)
            .spanId(RandomUtils.nextLong())
            .build();
    return tracer.nextSpan(TraceContextOrSamplingFlags.create(traceContext));
}
```

Is it possible to do same in spring sleuth with openTelemetry, https://spring-projects-experimental.github.io/spring-cloud-sleuth-otel/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#how-to-set-up-sleuth-with-otel

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and found an alternative solution with starting new scope:

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils;
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.CurrentTraceContext;
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.TraceContext;
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Tracer;
import org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.internal.EncodingUtils;

void test(String traceId) {
    CurrentTraceContext currentContext = tracer.currentTraceContext();
    // TODO handle currentContext is undefined
    TraceContext newTraceContext = tracer.traceContextBuilder()
            .traceId(traceId)
            .parentId(currentContext.context().traceId())
            .spanId(EncodingUtils.fromLong(RandomUtils.nextLong()))
            .sampled(true)
            .build();
    try (CurrentTraceContext.Scope scope = currentContext.newScope(newTraceContext)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to solve it. Spring slueth interface doesn't support it out of box, Need to use OpenTelemetry native library for creating span with a traceId.

```
import io.opentelemetry.api.OpenTelemetry;
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.*;
import io.opentelemetry.context.Context;
import io.opentelemetry.context.Scope;


private Span createNewSpan(String traceId) {
        SpanContext remoteContext = SpanContext.create(traceId,SpanId.fromLong(RandomUtils.nextLong()),
                TraceFlags.getSampled(),
                TraceState.getDefault());
        return openTelemetry.getTracer("").spanBuilder("TEST_SPAN")
                .setParent(Context.current().with(Span.wrap(remoteContext)))
                .startSpan();
}

    Span span = createNewSpan(traceId);
    try (Scope scope = span.makeCurrent()) {

    }finally {
        span.end();
    }
```